# Single page application route in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm building a single page application with asp.net net mvc4 and javascript.

My javascript has it's own routing engine, so I would like to have all routes under root handled by javascript, and all routes under `api` handled by server side. I.e.:

```
/             <--- javascript handles 
/api          <--- ASP.NET MVC handles
```

However, I don't have a clue of how to tell ASP.NET MVC to not handle these routes, and what I tried so far doesn't even run:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Client",
            url: "/",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index",  }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "API",
            url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Tasks", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Any ideas are welcome, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what routing means in the case of MVC.  MVC must use routes, at the very least a basic default route (and if using WebApi an Api route as well).  The routing engine is what allows MVC to create the correct controllers based on the url, without it, MVC can't function.  There is no way for JavaScript to handle this function for MVC.

Comment: His question made sense.  Client-side routing intercepts and handles all the route changes *while the SPA is running* - but a user might bookmark one of the links and return to it later.  When that happens, the server-side routing must be wired up in such a way that the SPA can be reloaded so that the right client-side route can be served up.  Otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't have defaults for parameters that don't exist in the route URL, unless you use a catch-all parameter.  You'd also need to create your API route first to avoid it being consumed by the catch-all route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "API",
    url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller="Tasks", action="Index", id=UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{*catchall}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

update: I should mention that in this case, .NET MVC will still forward any requests not matching "API" on to "Home/Index," which in your case should serve up the entry point of your client-side MVC framework.

Comment: Static resources are being blocked by the route, it returns the index.html page for those calls as well. How do we get around this?

Comment: You'd probably need to have several "catch-all" routes, one on each controller, rather than a single catch-all that handles everything.  For example, if you have `Views/Home`, `Views/Foo`, `Views/Bar`, and `HomeController`, `FooController`, `BarController`, then you'd have a catch-all in all three of those controllers that handle calls that include `/Home`, `/Foo`, and `/Bar` respectively. As long as none of your controllers conflict with the paths to your static resources (e.g. don't have `Views/Content` if your static files are in `/Content`, you should be fine. Tell me if that doesn't help.